# My input is not working in React, onChange looks good too

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My input element doesn't let me type into it, it will show up, with the value i want, but I cannot delete or edit anything in the input. Everything is spelled correctly from what I have seen.

I've been googling and have searched multiple SO forms, none have been able to help me. Which is why I am asking now

```
const GuestName =(props)=>{
    if(props.isEditing){
        return(
        <form>
        <input type='text' className='edit-guest-input'
         value={props.guestName} onChange={e => props.editGuest(e.target.value)}/>
         </form>
        )
    }

    return (
    <span>{props.guestName}</span>
    )
}
```

the above is the input that will not work

```
  editGuest=(id, name)=>{
    this.setState({
      guest: this.state.guest.map((guest) =>{
        if(id===guest.id){
          return{
            ...guest,
            name
          }}
          return guest
      })
    })
  }
```

this is the code for the onChange event.

```
const GuestList =(props)=>

    <div>

        <ul>
            {props.guest.filter( guest => !props.filterUnconfirmedGuest || guest.isConfirmed)
            .map((guest, index) =>   <Guest 
                            key={index}
                            guestName={guest.guestName}
                            toggleGuestConfirmed={props.toggleGuestConfirmed}
                            isConfirmed={guest.isConfirmed}
                            toggleEditGuest={()=> props.toggleEditGuest(guest.id)}
                            isEditing={guest.isEditing}
                            editGuest={editedName=> props.editGuest(editedName, guest.id)}
                            removeGuest={()=> props.removeGuest(guest.id)}
                                />)}
       </ul>
    </div>
```

The first argument is passed in here

Probably a minor issue that I am too tired to notice lol. Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: one arg vs 2 args

Comment: It was passed in the parent component, sorry should've posted that, not ar my PC or I would

Comment: can you show us where the id is mapped? most probably the bug is caused by that

Comment: I will for sure, I'm out right now but will once i get home

Comment: I updated it with the code to show the first argument being passed

Comment: in ```editGuest``` shouldn't it be ```guestName: name```?

Comment: YUP!! omg i'm so stupid... rookie mistake. Too tired, Thank you @MatinSasan!!!!!

Comment: Could you accept my answer pls :D @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in `editGuest` it should be  `guestName: name` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `editGuests` function with one argument

```
onChange={e => props.editGuest(e.target.value)}
```

But it has two arguments in the definition

```
editGuest=(id, name)=>{

}
```

Comment: It's passed in the parent component. I'm gonna post that code once I get home

Comment: if it's passed, then you have to add it here. `onChange={e => props.editGuest(passedValue, e.target.value)}`

Comment: You cannot call `editGuest` with one argument, as it defined with two.

Comment: I updated it with the code to show the first argument being passed , does this work?